# Connecting to a Server message queue using Reactor Netty

Tags: java, httpclient, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I am trying to connect to a message queue running on a docker container using Reactor Netty. I am doing this as standalone, not using SpringFlux because of dependency issues.

From the examples in the Reactor Netty documentation I saw there is a way to connect to the Server and get a response:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response =
                HttpClient.create()
                          .headers(h -> h.add("my header", my_header)
                          .get()
                          .uri(my_uri)
                          .responseContent() 
                          .aggregate()       
                          .asString()        
                          .block();
    }
```

but when I try afterwards to display the output via System.out.println() nothing happens.

I also tried to understand how to use:

`Flux<V> response(BiFunction<HttpClientResponse,ByteBufFlux,Publisher<V>> receiver)`

But I am not sure exactly what to do.
I saw in the documentation there is a class called Connection, which uses a TCPClient and has a method subscribe.

I am kind of lost, can you possibly point me in the right direction of implementing this in Reactor Netty without  the use of spring-flux?

Thank you

EDIT:

After some experimentation i got this:

```
private Disposable subscribe() {
    return HttpClient.create()
               .headers(h -> h.add("my header", my_header)
               .get()
               .uri(my_uri)
               .response((res, bytes) - > {
                   System.out.println(bytes.asString());
                   return bytes.asString();})
               .subscribe();
}
```

This gives me a FluxHandle, how can I use that to actually read the body of the response?

Comment: The example with `block` should work, if that's not the case please open an issue.
Also you can trace the network traffic with adding `.wiretap(true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to subscibe and read the data recieved from the Server and even transform the data to JSON, using the `jackson` library, to be more easily read by my code.

```
private Disposable subscribe() {
    return HttpClient.create()
               .headers(h -> h.add("my header", my_header)
               .get()
               .uri(my_uri)
               .response((resp, bytes) -> {
                    return bytes.asString();
                })
                .subscribe(response -> {
                    try {
                        consumeData(new ObjectMapper()
                                .readValue(response, MyData.class));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR converting to json: " + ex);
                    }
                    });
}
```

it seems that when using the subscribe() method i can listen to incoming responses and do something with them. I still need to add a way for the connection to close when the server stops, or the message queue is shut down, so the client doesn't hang on non-existent message queue.